# How can I assign a float variable to an unsigned int variable, bit image, not cast

Tags: c++

I know this is a bizarre thing to do, and it's not portable.  But I have an allocated array of unsigned ints, and I occasionaly want to "store" a float in it.  I don't want to cast the float or convert it to the closest equivalent int; I want to store the exact bit image of the float in the allocated space of the unsigned int, such that I could later retrieve it as a float and it would retain its original float value.

Comment: How do you know if an arbitrary element of the array is actually an "occasional" float?

Comment: If this is something you want to do, you might want to consider using a `union`, rather than an explicit `int` that's actually a `float` . . .

Comment: @ruakh: Using a union would almost surely result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: `std::vector<boost::variant<int, float>>`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Nonsense. Unless, I suppose, you take the view that writing a program will almost surely result in undefined behavior. A union is the standard way to store either of two types in the same memory location. It's then the programmer's responsibility to make sure (s)he knows which type is stored -- but it's *always* the programmer's responsibility to write correct code, so nothing has changed.

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved through a simple copy:

```
uint32_t dst;
float    src = get_float();

char * const p = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&dst);

std::copy(p, p + sizeof(float), reinterpret_cast<char *>(&src));

// now read dst
```

Copying backwards works similarly.

Answer (score 2):

Just do a reinterpret cast of the respective memory location:

```
float f = 0.5f;
unsigned int i = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(&f);
```

or the more C-like version:

```
unsigned int i = *(unsigned int*)&f;
```

From your question text I assume you are aware that this breaks if `float` and `unsigned int` don't have the same size, but on most usual platforms both should be 32-bit.

**EDIT:** As Kerrek pointed out, this seems to be undefined behaviour. But I still stand to my answer, as it is short and precise and should indeed work on any practical compiler (convince me of the opposite). But look at Kerrek's answer if you want a UB-free answer.

Comment: @KerrekSB Sure, and what do you expect from casting the raw bits of a `float` to an `unsigned int` other than UB? Isn't a `reinterpret_cast` almost always UB?

Comment: Nothing, I just expected an answer to the OP's question! ;-) Casting is only OK if it is to a char pointer. As my Aunt Cecile says: *If it's C++ and it's a pointer, it better be a char pointer!*

Comment: @Kerrek And the answer would be? DON'T DO IT, IT'S PLATFORM-DEPENDENT, AHHH!

Comment: Not in the least. The OP only wants to store and retrieve, so there's nothing platform dependent (subject to the int having sufficient size).

Comment: @KerrekSB Ah Ok, I see. I stand to my much shorter answer, but you get a +1 for a UB free answer. I didn't actually know it is UB, I thought it is just platform-dependent. Actually I think I have even seen boost do this in their hash functions implementation for floats (of course after making sure the sizes match).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reinterpret_cast` if you really have to. You don't even need to play with pointers/addresses as other answers mention. For example

```
int i;
reinterpret_cast<float&>(i) = 10;

std::cout << std::endl << i << " " << reinterpret_cast<float&>(i) << std::endl;
```

also works (and prints `1092616192 10` if you are qurious ;).

EDIT:

From C++ standard (about reinterpret_cast):

> 5.2.10.7 A pointer to an object can be explicitly converted to a pointer to an object of different type.Except that converting an
>   rvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (where T1
>   and T2 are object types and where the alignment requirements of T2 are
>   no stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type yields the
>   original pointer value, the result of such a pointer conversion is
>   unspecified.
>
> 5.2.10.10 10 An lvalue expression of type T1 can be cast to the type “reference to T2” if an expression of type “pointer to T1” can be
>   explicitly converted to the type “pointer to T2” using a
>   reinterpret_cast. That is, a reference cast `reinterpret_cast<T&>(x)`
>   has the same effect as the conversion
>   `*reinterpret_cast<T*>(&x)` with the built-in & and * operators. The result is an lvalue that refers to the same object as the source
>   lvalue, but with a different type. No temporary is created, no copy is
>   made, and constructors (12.1) or conversion functions (12.3) are not
>   called.67)

So it seems that consistently reinterpreting pointers is not undefined behavior, and using references has the same result as taking address, reintepreting and deferencing obtained pointer. I still claim that this is not undefined behavior.

Comment: Techincally as far as I understand C++ specification, if you do it consistently (mean accesing given variable ony in this way) then it is not undefined behaviour. Only if you acces this variable also directly it is - I have done it, but only for demonstration purposes.

Comment: I don't think so. It's just undefined behaviour, that's all.