# Copy bit pattern: float to uint32_t

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, primitive-types, reinterpret-cast

Copying bit pattern of a `float` value into a `uint32_t` or vice versa (not casting them), we can copy bits byte-to-byte using `std::copy` or `memcpy`. Another way is to use `reinterpret_cast` as below (?):

```
float f = 0.5f;
uint32_t i = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&f);
```

or

```
uint32_t i;
reinterpret_cast<float&>(i) = 10;
```

However there is a [claim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365143/how-can-i-assign-a-float-variable-to-an-unsigned-int-variable-bit-image-not-ca) that says two `reinterpret_cast` used above, invokes undefined behavior. Is that true? How?

Comment: As stated by the answer it is UB.  a assertion that `sizeof(uint32_t) == sizeof(float)` though should be all you need to feel confident that it will work.

Comment: @NathanOliver But if the compiler does type-based alias optimizations then it could reasonably break the behaviour if you don't supply `-fno-strict-aliasing` or something.

Comment: @TartanLlama Good point.  checking `alignof` might also be needed.

Comment: Note that there's even discussion as to whether the `memcpy` approach is defined. See [here](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3751.pdf) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114397/constructing-a-trivially-copyable-object-with-memcpy).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is undefined behaviour as it breaks the strict aliasing rule:

> `[basic.lval]/10:` If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the
>   following types the behavior is undefined
>   — the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a type similar (as defined in 4.4) to the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type
>   of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or non-
>   static data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate
>   or contained union),
>
> — a type that is a (possibly cv-qualifded) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a char or unsigned char type.

Since `uint32_t` is none of the above when trying to access an object of type `float`, the behaviour is undefined.